# Meaning of the word 'en'

Tags: meaning

While reading Paulo Coelho's novel, I came across a word that left me doubting whether it was of English origin. Following is the sentence:

> She fell in love for the first time when she was eleven, en route from her house to school.

What is the meaning of the word *en*?

Please elaborate on its meaning, origin and usage.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The en here doesn't mean anything except as part of 'en route', which is imported from French and means 'on or along the way'. See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enroute. There are other phrases of this kind, such as 'en banc' or 'en prise'.

There is another word 'en' which is printer's jargon and means the width on the page occupied by the letter 'n' (and is half an 'em').

Comment: +1 *en* and *em* are also used to indicate two types of dashes. It really has nothing to do with the question, but en and em dashes are one of those things that make books look good.

Comment: Oooh thanks! I've been using "em" in CSS for years, and never wondered where it came from!

Answer (score 15):

The word 'en' is actually of French origin. It can mean 'on', 'in', 'inside' or 'along' depending on context.
The [disambiguation page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_Route) on Wikipedia says :
"En route is a French phrase which means "on the way" or "along the way". "

Comment: The only other uses of "en" I can recall hearing in English are "en passant" and "en guarde". Those are both technical terms (from chess and fencing respectively), and were borrowed into English wholesale. I suspect "en route" is of the same provenence, but from road racing.

Comment: @T.E.D. I don't think "en route" has anything to do with road racing specifically. I've mainly heard and used it to refer to something done incidentally to travel, for instance "we went from Lincoln to London but called in at Cambridge en route." I suspect that, if it has a specific origin, it comes from the 18th and 19th century Grand Tour.

Answer (score 2):

*En* is a French preposition that commonly appears in phrases borrowed from French. In this case, *en route* is a French phrase that means, roughly, *on the way* ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/62618)).

Other common French loan phrases involving *en* include:

- *[en avant](https://oed.com/view/Entry/381023)* - forward. 1823 Ld. Byron Let.

  > 22 Apr. (1980) X. 156   But never mind—‘*En Avant!*’ live while you can.
- *[en banc](https://oed.com/view/Entry/56701627)* - all or a quorum of judges.

  > 1986   J. Batten Judges 220   Before the Second World War, the appeal courts would sit *en banc* for the most part.
- *[en déshabillé](https://oed.com/view/Entry/381034)* - in undress.

  > 1877   C. Reade Woman-hater I. vii. 172   Let me catch her *en déshabille*, with her porter on one side, and her lover on the other.
- *[en l'air](https://oed.com/view/Entry/381043)* - in the air, figuratively meaning unsupported.

  > 1964   W. B. Pemberton Battles of Boer War vi. 164   The extreme right of the Boers was practically *en l'air* and deserted.
- *[en plein](https://oed.com/view/Entry/62559)* - in full; betting entirely on one side or number in roulette.

  > 1966   C. Robertson Judas Spies i. 9   He had been sitting at a roulette table..playing the even chances mostly, occasionally trying his luck *en plein*.
- *[en pointe](https://oed.com/view/Entry/381048)* - dancing on the toe in ballet.

  > 1959   Times 1 Sept. 11/3   Miss Doris Lainë..did a wonderfully neat hop *en pointe*.
- *[en poste](https://oed.com/view/Entry/381050)* - in an official (usually diplomatic) position.

  > 1962   John o' London's 31 May 517/1   While he was *en poste* in Paris he gathered much of the material.
- *[en suite](https://oed.com/view/Entry/380843)* - forming a suite, often of adjoining rooms.

  > 2006   Peak District Life Spring 33/3   Crisp blue and white striped bed linen and curtains give a fresh feel to the guest bedroom and *en-suite* bathroom.

Outside of French borrowing, this preposition *en* is not a generative English word. For instance, *en the countertop*, *en road*, or *en top of the world* don't work, except as an awkward substitution for *in* or *on*.